# Highlight untranslated Django strings

Tags: django, internationalization

In my po file, some strings are translated, but others not:

```
msgid "Hello there"
msgstr "Hallo du"

msgid "Goodbye"
msgstr ""
```

As is intended, this transparently falls back - I see `Goodbye` although no translated text is present. However, these strings can be overlooked easily (especially if the languages are quite similar).

Is there a way I can add a note for untranslated strings, so that it shows up as

`UNTRANSLATED:Goodbye/UNTRANSLATED`

in the user interface and my test users can know that the string is not final yet?

Comment: You want to add a note as a comment, or have the actual string display as "UNTRANSLATED" for the user? The latter is inadvisable from a UX perspective

Comment: @ubadub I want the actual display string be that way, so that the current test users know that that part of the interface is not final.

Comment: Why not just use your editor's find/replace key to replaced every empty string with `UNTRANSLATED:Goodbye/UNTRANSLATED`?

Comment: @ubadub That works, but it really doesn't scale; all kinds of different tools (marketing, linters, translation platforms, local translation scripts) across different company divisions need to interact with the po files, so I can't just check in the modified files. And in my company, quite sensibly, deployments are only possible if the code is checked into git (and for some systems, the git master branch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monkey-patch `django.utils.translation.trans_real.do_translate`, like this:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.safestring import SafeData, mark_safe
from django.utils.translation import trans_real

def highlight_untranslated():
    def monkeypatched_do_translate(message, translation_function):
        eol_message = message.replace(
            str('\r\n'), str('\n')).replace(str('\r'), str('\n'))

        if len(eol_message) == 0:
            result = type(message)("")
        else:
            trans_real._default = (
                trans_real._default or
                trans_real.translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE))
            translation_object = getattr(
                trans_real._active, "value", trans_real._default)

            result = getattr(
                translation_object, translation_function)(eol_message)

            # Untranslated string? If so, add a warning
            default_catalog = getattr(trans_real._default, '_catalog', None)
            if default_catalog and eol_message in default_catalog:
                catalog = getattr(translation_object, '_catalog', None)
                if catalog and eol_message not in catalog:
                    result = '__UNTRANSLATED:%s/UNTRANSLATED__' % eol_message

        if isinstance(message, SafeData):
            return mark_safe(result)

        return result

    trans_real.do_translate = monkeypatched_do_translate
```